# Scraping HTML table in Python lxml

Tags: python, web-scraping, lxml

The question may sound easy, but I am facing difficulty in solving it. I have a table like following:

```
<table><tbody>
<tr>
<td>2003</td>
<td><span class="positive">1.19</span> </td>
<td><span class="negative">-0.48</span> </td>
</tr>
```

My code is following:

```
 from lxml import etree

 for elem in tree.xpath('//*[@id="printcontent"]/div[8]/div/table/tbody/tr'):
    for c in elem.xpath("//td"):
        if(c.getchildren()): # for the <span> thing
            text = c.xpath("//span/text()")
        else:
             text = c.text
```

But I am unable to iterate over the "td" elements. I have been trying this whole day but of no avail!! I want to get 2003. 1.19, and -0.48.

Kindly help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you have HTML, not XML. Therefore, use lxml.html, not lxml.etree
to parse the data. If `data.html` looks like this:

```
<table><tbody>
<tr>
<td>2003</td>
<td><span class="positive">1.19</span> </td>
<td><span class="negative">-0.48</span> </td>
</tr>
```

then

```
import lxml.html as LH
tree = LH.parse('data.html')
print([td.text_content() for td in tree.xpath('//td')])
```

yields

```
['2003', '1.19 ', '-0.48 ']
```

If

```
for elem in tree.xpath('//*[@id="printcontent"]/div[8]/div/table/tbody/tr'):
```

is not returning any `elem`s, then you need to show us enough HTML to help us debug why this XPath is not working.

Comment: bravo! Yes I made this XML - HTML mistake